# Remove Empty Node, Keeping required elements on populated node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
<exx:XItemLocDesc xmlns:exx="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/XItemLocDesc/v1">
         <exx:XItemLocDtl>
            <exx:hier_value/>
            <exx:primary_supp>XXX</exx:primary_supp>
            <exx:primary_cntry>XXX</exx:primary_cntry>
            <exx:status>XXX</exx:status>
            <exx:store_ord_mult>XXXX</exx:store_ord_mult>
            <exx:receive_as_type/>
            <exx:taxable_ind/>
            <exx:ext_uin_ind>XXX</exx:ext_uin_ind>
            <exx:source_method>XXX</exx:source_method>
            <exx:source_wh>XXX</exx:source_wh>
         </exx:XItemLocDtl>
         <exx:XItemLocDtl>
            <exx:hier_value/>
            <exx:primary_supp/>
            <exx:primary_cntry/>
            <exx:status/>
            <exx:store_ord_mult/>
            <exx:receive_as_type/>
            <exx:taxable_ind/>
         </exx:XItemLocDtl>
         <exx:XItemLocDtl>
            <exx:hier_value/>
            <exx:primary_supp/>
            <exx:primary_cntry/>
            <exx:status/>
            <exx:store_ord_mult/>
            <exx:receive_as_type/>
            <exx:taxable_ind/>
         </exx:XItemLocDtl>
</exx:XItemLocDesc>
```

I wish make a generic solution to remove Empty List, but keep 'minOccurs=1' elements..

Note, that the elements are required.

```
<exx:hier_value/>
<exx:primary_supp/>
<exx:primary_cntry/>
<exx:status/>
<exx:store_ord_mult/>
<exx:receive_as_type/>
<exx:taxable_ind/>
```

If i use the following XSLT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(.)) != ''
                        or count(@*[normalize-space(string(.)) != '']) > 0
                        or count(descendant::*[normalize-space(string(.)) != '']) > 0
                        or count(descendant::*/@*[normalize-space(string(.)) != '']) > 0">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(.)) != ''">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My result is

```
<exx:XItemLocDesc xmlns:exx="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/XItemLocDesc/v1">
   <exx:XItemLocDtl>
      <exx:primary_supp>XXX</exx:primary_supp>
      <exx:primary_cntry>XXX</exx:primary_cntry>
      <exx:status>XXX</exx:status>
      <exx:store_ord_mult>XXXX</exx:store_ord_mult>
      <exx:ext_uin_ind>XXX</exx:ext_uin_ind>
      <exx:source_method>XXX</exx:source_method>
      <exx:source_wh>XXX</exx:source_wh>
   </exx:XItemLocDtl>
</exx:XItemLocDesc>
```

And i wish keep the required field on Node that contains some content..

Like this:

```
<exx:XItemLocDesc xmlns:exx="http://www.oracle.com/retail/integration/base/bo/XItemLocDesc/v1">
         <exx:XItemLocDtl>
            <exx:hier_value/>
            <exx:primary_supp>XXX</exx:primary_supp>
            <exx:primary_cntry>XXX</exx:primary_cntry>
            <exx:status>XXX</exx:status>
            <exx:store_ord_mult>XXXX</exx:store_ord_mult>
            <exx:receive_as_type/>
            <exx:taxable_ind/>
            <exx:ext_uin_ind>XXX</exx:ext_uin_ind>
            <exx:source_method>XXX</exx:source_method>
            <exx:source_wh>XXX</exx:source_wh>
         </exx:XItemLocDtl>
</exx:XItemLocDesc>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear. Would something like this work for you:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="required-names">
    <name>exx:hier_value</name>
    <name>exx:primary_supp</name>
    <name>exx:primary_cntry</name>
    <name>exx:status</name>
    <name>exx:store_ord_mult</name>
    <name>exx:receive_as_type</name>
    <name>exx:taxable_ind</name>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(node() or @* or name()=$required-names/name)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that storing the required names as qualified names (using a known prefix) is less than ideal. A better solution would store a combination of the local name and the namespace URI, so it wouldn't be affected in case the prefix has changed.

Comment: I need remove empty Nodes, but keeping required fields on nodes with some content.

Comment: @Stack I am not sure what you're trying to say. Let me point out that "empty node" can be interpreted in many different ways. I don't intend to go into that. My answer was only meant to show how to keep a node if it's on your "required" list, even if it is "empty".